# Regular Expression C#, HTML parse

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Please help.

I have a text from html, and I need to parse it.
Text:

> converter.rates =
>   {"3":{"USD":{"buy":27.950001,"sell":28.190001},"EUR":{"buy":32.049999,"sell":32.689999}},"8":{"RUB":{"buy":0.27,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":27.799999,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":31.700001,"sell":32.549999}},"41":{"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":31.950001,"sell":32.650002}},"46":{"RUB":{"buy":0.413,"sell":0.443},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":31.73,"sell":32.73}},"47":{"RUB":{"buy":0.41,"sell":0.448},"USD":{"buy":27.98,"sell":28.15},"EUR":{"buy":31.889999,"sell":32.540001}},"48":{"RUB":{"buy":0.4,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.099998,"sell":32.490002}},"52":{"RUB":{"buy":0.41,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":27.950001,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.5}},"77":{"RUB":{"buy":0.38,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":28.049999,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.049999,"sell":32.5}},"79":{"RUB":{"buy":0.412,"sell":0.444},"USD":{"buy":27.950001,"sell":28.799999},"EUR":{"buy":31.959999,"sell":33.099998}},"80":{"RUB":{"buy":0.38,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":28.030001,"sell":28.190001},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.450001}},"70":{"RUB":{"buy":0.39,"sell":0.42},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.200001}},"1":{"RUB":{"buy":0.42658,"sell":0.42658},"USD":{"buy":28.036648,"sell":28.036648},"EUR":{"buy":32.256161,"sell":32.256161}},"4":{"RUB":{"buy":0.42,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":27.950001,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":32.150002,"sell":32.599998}},"10":{"RUB":{"buy":0.414,"sell":0.435},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.599998}},"13":{"RUB":{"buy":0.275,"sell":0.46},"USD":{"buy":27.9,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":31.67,"sell":32.599998}},"15":{"RUB":{"buy":0.3749,"sell":0.4395},"USD":{"buy":27.985001,"sell":28.2075},"EUR":{"buy":32.036366,"sell":32.529091}},"31":{"RUB":{"buy":0.275,"sell":0.42},"USD":{"buy":27.9,"sell":28.139999},"EUR":{"buy":31.799999,"sell":32.400002}},"32":{"RUB":{"buy":0.42,"sell":0.5},"USD":{"buy":28.07,"sell":28.299999},"EUR":{"buy":32.150002,"sell":32.599998}},"39":{"USD":{"buy":28.07,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":32.150002,"sell":32.549999}},"40":{"RUB":{"buy":0.41,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":27.950001,"sell":28.139999},"EUR":{"buy":32.049999,"sell":32.400002}},"64":{"RUB":{"buy":0.4,"sell":0.425},"USD":{"buy":27.9,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.099998,"sell":32.599998}},"73":{"RUB":{"buy":0.4,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.299999},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.549999}},"74":{"RUB":{"buy":0.41,"sell":0.435},"USD":{"buy":28.049999,"sell":28.25},"EUR":{"buy":31.799999,"sell":32.5}},"85":{"RUB":{"buy":0.3,"sell":0.43},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.099998,"sell":32.52}},"86":{"RUB":{"buy":0.37,"sell":0.42},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.200001},"EUR":{"buy":32.0,"sell":32.799999}},"88":{"RUB":{"buy":0.35,"sell":0.5},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.15},"EUR":{"buy":32.099998,"sell":32.450001}},"90":{"RUB":{"buy":4.0,"sell":4.4},"USD":{"buy":28.0,"sell":28.15},"EUR":{"buy":31.950001,"sell":32.450001}}}

I need next info from it:

> code of bank - "3" 
>   and USD rate - 27.950001, 28.190001

My expression:

> @"(\d+)":..USD....\w+..(\d+.\d+)........(\d+.\d+)"

But it didn't work, because the USD does not always go first after the bank code

Comment: That's not HTML (not even close), that's a JSON object...

Comment: Paste everything after the `=` to this page: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and see what I'm talking about

Comment: ye poorly formatted json. lol. these are forex exchange rates.

Comment: I see. Can you tell me how to parse from here info.

Comment: Your expression is not a valid @-quouted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use regex, this can do it:

```
@"""(?<code>\d+)"":\{.*?(?<=""USD""):\{""buy"":(?<buy>\d+\.\d+),""sell"":(?<sell>\d+.\d+)\}"
```

It is build from your example. Basically it creates three named Groups `'code'`, `'buy'` and `'sell'`. Other than that it matches literal characters, only using a look behind '`(?<=""USD"")`' to find `'USD'` to get the wanted rates.

`Edit`:

If you have a html document and want to grap the '`converter.rates`' var as text, you can use this regex:

```
@"converter.rates\s?=.*\}\}\}"
```

It looks for the 3 '}' ending the string.

Answer (score 2):

This is a JSON document. JSON is a recursive format, and regular expressions are notoriously hard to use when parsing recursive data.

Please use a specified parser, like [NewtonSoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var rawData = @"converter.rates = { ... }"; // original string
var rawJson = rawData.Substring("converter.rates = ".Length); // remove the prefix
var json = JObject.Parse(rawJson); // convert to a JSON data structure
```

Then you can use it like a dictionary:

```
foreach(var codeEntry in json)
{
    foreach(var currencyEntry in codeEntry.Value)
    {
        var code = codeEntry.Key;
        var currency = currencyEntry.Key;
        var buy = currencyEntry.Value["buy"].Value<double>();
        var sell = currencyEntry.Value["buy"].Value<double>();
        Console.WriteLine($"code of bank - {code} and {currency} rate - {buy}, {sell} ");
    }
}
```

Comment: original string is html document, how I get only "converter.rates = { ... }" ?